# NetBeans 7(regex): find a function with only one argument

Tags: regex, netbeans

```
function test('argument one', 'argument two') {}

function test('argument one') {}
```

I want to find all files that contains **function test** with **only one argument**.

Can anybody help me? Please! Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here

```
 function test\([^,]*\)
```

And I highly recommend Actual Search & Replace

http://www.divlocsoft.com/#find%20and%20replace

(Or PowerGrep if you need to do this more)